# Convert MuseScore sheet music to solfege mp3 output

Tags: music, music-production, music-composing, music-sheet

I want to export my sheet music (*.mscz or *.mscx file produced by MuseScore) as an mp3 audio file but **with a solfa voice** as the output.

It is just simple interval exercises, not complex music.

Many apps doing this are using Aaahs and Ooohs.

Is there any software or website out there that can help me to achieve this.